# Get values of object using lodash

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I've to use lodash for get the values of this object: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=U1Z8tzY0

As you can see, I have one big object. I need to get all the `autonomias` names with the `activo` property set to `true`".

I've tried to use a lot of functions without result. I'm stuck.

And I can't find the way to do it properly after few days.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I expect all the `autonomias` with the `activo: true`:  { "andalucia", "aragon", "asturias", "canarias", etc }. In this file all is set to true, but in a near real example some "autonomias" are going to set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet should do the trick:

```
var res =  _(data)
             .chain()
                .result('autonomias')
                .filter({ activo: true }) 
                .pluck('name')
             .value();
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/bofxhakm/)

You could also use native Array methods:

```
var res = data.autonomias.filter(function (el) {
    return el.activo === true;
}).map(function (el) {
    return el.name;
});
```

Comment: Thanks you!, I finally made my solution, but your is really better.

Comment: I know, but needed to use lodash. Thanks you.

Comment: what if I need to get the full object instead only the name of an active `autonomia`?

Comment: Thank you. Saved a lot of time.